# Question on proving that $a \vert c$ if $ gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a \vert bc$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be positive integers such that $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a\vert bc$. Prove that $a \vert c$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Look at the prime divisors of a,b,c

Comment: this is Euclid's Lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Comment: If $ua+vb=1$ then $c=uac+vbc=(uc+v\frac{bc}a)\cdot a$

Comment: It's *Gauß'lemma*. *Euclid'slemma* is the case  $a$ prime.

Answer (score -1):

As $a|bc$, we have

$\gcd(a,bc)=a$

and

$\gcd(a,bc)\le\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(a,c)$

Because  $a\le c$, $\gcd(a,c)\le a$

Therefore $\gcd(a,c)=a$, therefore $a|c$.